# Why doesn't my error check work?

Tags: java, methods, error-handling, filenames

What I did was I made an error check that loops through everytime an invalid filename is entered by the user:

```
    public static Scanner readFile(String filename){
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    File input = new File(filename);
    Scanner sc = null;
    do {
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(input);
    }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Filename not valid. Please try again:");
            filename = stdin.nextLine();
    }
} while (!new File(filename).exists()); 
            return sc;
    }
```

I also have enough method that reads that file and puts the data into an array:

```
public static CO2Data[] readData(String filename){
File input = new File(filename);
    Scanner sc = null;
    try{
        sc = new Scanner(input);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Filename not valid");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
String info = sc.nextLine();
int total = sc.nextInt();
CO2Data[] arr = new CO2Data[total];
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
    arr[i] = new CO2Data();
    }
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){ 
    arr[i].setCountry(sc.next());
    arr[i].setTotalCO2(sc.nextDouble());
    arr[i].setRoadCO2(sc.nextDouble());
    arr[i].setCO2PerPerson(sc.nextDouble());
    arr[i].setCarsPerPerson(sc.nextInt());
    }
return arr;
}
```

The problem is that if I type an invalid filename first and then a valid name the program says the file is invalid however if I type a valid filename first then the program works fine. So how come typing a valid filename first works fine but typing an invalid name and then a valid name makes the program give me an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Well lets walk through the full scenario:

If you type an invalid filename the code will move to the catch block, waiting for you to type in a new filename with the line

`filename = stdin.nextLine();`

You type in a valid filename and the variable filename gets reset to the new filename (good so far)

Then we move on to the `While` block, which will check if the file exists (which it does!) good, so we move to the return statement (which holds the issue)

In the return statement you return the scanner that was holding the **previous invalid** filename.  You need to remake the scanner with the new file before you return it.

I would probably edit the while loop  to read

```
public static Scanner readFile(String filename){
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
File input = new File(filename);
Scanner sc = null;
do {
    try {
        input = new File(filename);
        sc = new Scanner(input);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Filename not valid. Please try again:");
        filename = stdin.nextLine();
    }
} while (!input.exists());
    return sc;
}
```

this way we create a new `File` class after we receive the valid input and then return a new `Scanner` holding the new `input`

Comment: There was a problem with the return statement. In order to return the new scanner the filenotfound exception must be either caught or thrown.

Comment: @DavidRolfe err now were good lol, sorry Friday my brain is slower

Comment: Even the edited program still gives me the same problem. What I'm wondering is, is the problem with that method or with the way those methods are called?

Comment: @DavidRolfe hmm.  could you update your answer with the error message?  Possibly a stack trace if you have one

Answer (score 0):

You don't create new input from filename - so you always use the first filename in Scanner. This should work:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
public static Scanner readFile(String filename){
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc = null;
    File input;
    do {
        input = new File(filename);
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(input);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Filename not valid. Please try again:");
            filename = stdin.nextLine();
        }
    } while (!input.exists());
    return sc;
}
```

Comment: With that code the exact same thing happens as before when it works if I put a valid file name the first time but doesn't work if I put an invalid filename followed by a valid filename.

Comment: You still need to change the while line to check if the `input` exists, not a new file, else the same problem will occur.  ^^

Comment: Problem 2. I changed the while loop to say while (!input.exists()); however I get a compiler error that says variable input not found. I was sure I declared it earlier in my code but the compiler can't find it.

Comment: @DavidRolfe oh thats because he moved the `File input = new...` line to inside the loop.  If you leave that line outside and just use `input = new File(filename);` it would work.  (that's what I did on my updated answer)

Comment: You don't have to reuse the input variable, this version should work. I tried it and it asks for a filename until it gets existing file and then returns Scanner for it. Where do you use this function?

Comment: @jakub.petr no your version will not return the scanner for the new valid file.  The wile loop will see the file exists before you create a new scanner thus returning the old scanner, remember its a do-while not a while loop.  That last `while (!new File(filename).exists());` executes after the `catch` block

Comment: So which while loop will return the valid filename? The code is still giving me the exact same output where if you enter an invalid filename it doesn't work. It's weird because it works fine if you put in a valid filename first.